# JPA one way cascade operations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following JPA 2.0 models:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", targetEntity = Department.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Department> departments;

...
}

@Entity
public class Department {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private Company company;

...
}
```

When I try to remove Company, everything is fine - all departments are removed. But when I try to remove Department, it throws the following exception:
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [my.model.Department#]

Is it possible to configure it this way, that when I remove Department nothing happens with Company?

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH
```

on Department model does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are not deleting the referenced `Department` from `private List<Department> departments;` in your `Company` instance so the deleted instance is still referenced.

Remove the deleted department from the list as well and it should work.

Comment: I can't remove it from deparments list since this property it is not initialized (FetchType is set to LAZY and I didn't fetched deparments collection manually).

Comment: I am not sure how the department instance can be passed to `persist` if it is not loaded. Could you please add the code where you load the data and delete the Department? Have you tried to work around the issue by triggering the loading programmatically or with a fetch join?

Comment: Before remove I fetched Department once again, did `department.getCompany().getDepartments().remove(department)` and then removed department and everything works fine.
I still don't know why it tried to save departments collection from Company while it was not initialized - the type was PersistenceBag.

Answer (score 1):

If you add orphan-deletion in `Company`:

(JPA 2.0-way)

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", 
             targetEntity = Department.class,
             fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
             cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
             orphanRemoval=true)
  private List<Department> departments;
```

(Hibernate-way)

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", 
             targetEntity = Department.class,
             fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
             cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
             org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
  private List<Department> departments;
```

You can delete a department by doing:

```
company.getDepartments().remove(department);
```

and then storing the `Company` (or upon commiting the transaction) (given that a `Department` can be owned by one and only one `Company`. (No need to tell the `EntityManager` to remove the `Department`..)

Comment: OK, but why should I save Company if there is no change in "company" table? I would like to remove Department.

Comment: You are using JPA now, you need not worry about table operations. It is up to the JPA-provider to create the necessary queries, it probably won't run a query if there is nothing to update. When thinking about the problem at hand with a database perspective one might conclude that the operation is "remove a department", but that is just because that is the way you solve the problem in the database. The real thing you want to implement is "this department does no longer exist as part of this company" (since company owns its departments.)

Comment: In general, when you have an association between entities, if you can say that one side "owns" the other ("does it make sense to have this entity without a connection to this other entity?"), then all operations on the owned side should be done through persisting the owning side.

Comment: OK, I understand that this approach allows to implement business criteria much easier. But let's say Company has 1 million departments, then I need to load them into memory to remove just one entry - that's the problem.

Comment: The way I usually work with JPA is that I try to do it the JPA-way first, if that turns out to not scale I'll do another round and try to speed things up. In this case, if you see that deleting through delete-orphan is too slow/resource consuming, then delete it directly through EntityManager (although this will break with the fact that a department is owned by a company). Also, loading stuff into memory isn't a bad thing, chances are the company in question will be used for something during the execution of the program, which then will be much faster, as the company is already in memory.